# How to properly add urdf, config and launch directories to CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: urdf, ros-melodic, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am receiving errors (below) suggesting my `CMakeLists.txt` file does not properly define my `launch` folder, which contains `.launch` files, and my `urdf` and `config` folders within my `src` folder, which are used for various things.

```
No such file or directory: /snap/robot/x1/opt/ros/melodic/share/mapping/src/urdf/clearpath_jackal.urdf.xacro
RLException: while processing /snap/robot/x1/opt/ros/melodic/share/mapping/launch/robot_simulation.launch:
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [['/snap/robot/x1/opt/ros/melodic/lib/xacro/xacro', '/snap/robot/x1/opt/ros/melodic/share/mapping/src/urdf/clearpath_jackal.urdf.xacro', '--inorder']] returned with code [2].     
Param xml is <param command="$(find xacro)/xacro $(find mapping)/src/urdf/clearpath_jackal.urdf.xacro --inorder" name="robot_description"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Here's my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

project(mapping)

cmake_policy(SET CMP0054 OLD)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
        roscpp
        rospy
        std_msgs
        gazebo_ros
        cartographer_ros
        rosbridge_server
        jackal_control
        jackal_description
        gazebo_ros REQUIRED
        )

catkin_package(
        LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
        CATKIN_DEPENDS
        roscpp
        rospy
        std_msgs
        gazebo_ros
        cartographer_ros
        rosbridge_server
        jackal_control
        jackal_description
)

include_directories(
        ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GAZEBO_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

link_directories(
        ${GAZEBO_LIBRARY_DIRS}
)

catkin_install_python(PROGRAMS
        src/scripts/script_a.py
        src/scripts/script_b.py
        src/scripts/script_c.py
        src/scripts/script_d.py
        DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})

install(DIRECTORY launch/
        DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/launch
        PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE)
```

Can anyone point out whats wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364401/how-to-properly-add-urdf,-config-and-launch-directories-to-cmakelists.txt?/) by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on ROS Answers with karma: 501 on 2020-10-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kyrofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20478/kyrofa/) on 2020-10-29**:
`opt/ros/melodic/share/mapping/src/urdf/clearpath_jackal.urdf.xacro` seems like an odd path. Are you expecting your package to be installing that? I don't see anything in your CMakeLists.txt that indicates that you're installing any urdf files.

**Comment by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on 2020-11-02**:
Yeah I'm still having trouble with that. What makes it look odd to you?

**Comment by [kyrofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20478/kyrofa/) on 2020-11-02**:
Generally you don't see a `src` directory in an installed location.

**Comment by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on 2020-11-02**:
I have various folders within my packages `src` folder to store files used by each node, e.g. config and simulation related files. Should these be located outside the `src` folder? Or are you saying that something needs to be done in `CMakeLists.txt` to better specify their location beyond the answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I always do it like this:

```
install(DIRECTORY config launch meshes urdf
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION})
```

And a general comment:

> my `CMakeLists.txt` file does not properly define my `launch` folder

this may be language (English isn't my first language), but: the only thing you do with the `install(..)` is tell CMake you'd like the directories (in this case, could also be FILES, PROGRAMS, etc) to be copied to a `DESTINATION`.

You don't *define* anything, or at least not in the programming language sense.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on 2020-10-30**:
Perfect. I certainly understand your comment.... this makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the help :)